# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am getting the error "Permission Denied" on my Raspberry Pi:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import cv2

# Upper limit
_Servo1UL = 250
_Servo0UL = 230

# Lower Limit
_Servo1LL = 75
_Servo0LL = 70


ServoBlaster = open('/dev/servoblaster', 'w')       
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)                
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)     
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)    
frontalface = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")     
profileface = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_profileface.xml")
```

To further help with my problem, this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anisrahali/Desktop/PiFace.py", line 14, in <module>
    ServoBlaster = open('/dev/servoblaster', 'w')       # ServoBlaster is what we use to control the servo motors
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/servoblaster'
```

I also tried the following:

- tried to reinstal servoblaster using SSH

Thank you!

Comment: You're running this code as a user that does not have permission to write to that file.

Comment: Try running the same command as sudo.